# Azure Databricks working with mounted blobs in Python

Tags: azure, mount, azure-databricks, tfrecord

I've mounted a container (which contains tfrecords) to my Azure Databricks notebook with a shared access signature. Everything seems to be okay so far, since I can see my blobs if I run `dbutils.fs.ls("dbfs:/mnt/testmount")`.

However, I seem to be missing something fundamental here. I wish to train a model with the tfrecords from my mount, but it seems like I can't just access them outright with a path name, like `dbfs:/mnt/testmount/<my_files>` or simply `/mnt/testmount/<my_files>`.

Is there some other way to do this? Perhaps the mounting way is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
filePath = 'dbfs/mnt/testmount/'

or 

filePath = '/dbfs/mnt/testmount/'
```

***In some cases dbutils.fs.ls("dbfs:/mnt/testmount/") doesn't work***

Answer (score 0):

below should work.

```
mount_path = '/mnt/testmount/'
dbuitls.fs.ls(mount_path)
```

you rootpath should start with '/'